# StringJoin in Thread not working

Tags: string-manipulation

Here is what I have tried first.

```
Thread[f["x", {"1", "2"}]]
```

`{f["x", "1"], f["x", "2"]}`

But the weirdest thing happened when I substituted `StringJoin` for `f`

```
Thread[StringJoin["x", {"1", "2"}]]
```

`"x12"`

*I thought it would be like this below*

```
{"x1","x2"}
```

**Is there anyone who can explain this?**

Comment: Why use `Thread` for this?  `Table["x"<>n, {n, {"1","2"}}]` or `"x"<>#&/@{"1","2"}` seem like more straightforward ways to get this result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Thread >> Possible Issues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html):

- ***"Thread evaluates the whole expression before threading"***

Wrap `StringJoin` with [`Unevaluated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) to prevent evaluation of `StringJoin` before `Thread` gets to work:

```
Thread[Unevaluated @ StringJoin["x", {"1", "2"}]]
```

> ```
> {"x1", "x2"}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use

```
Thread[foo["x", {"1", "2"}]] /. foo -> StringJoin
```

> ```
> {"x1", "x2"}
> ```